# How to create lvm volume in other directory rather than /dev

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, storage, lvm

We know that we can use vgcreate to create a group and lvcreate to create a volume. And the volume would be /dev/mapper/$group/$volume, but if we want the volume to be created at say $dir/mapper/$group/$volume.
I saw someone write a program which can do this, does anybody know how he did it?

Comment: Why do you think this would be useful?

Answer (score 1):

It is set in the configuration file (usually /etc/lvm/lvm.conf):

```
# This section allows you to configure which block devices should
# be used by the LVM system.
devices {

    # Where do you want your volume groups to appear ?
    dir = "/dev"

    # An array of directories that contain the device nodes you wish
    # to use with LVM2.
    scan = [ "/dev" ]
```